# WPF Datagrid Column Format Number to include commas

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I thought this would be rather simple and probably is but I cannot find anything on google. I have a WPF application with a datagrid bound to my object which contains properties of type bool, string & int. Where int is displayed I want to show 30,000 rather than 30000. How is this acheieve?

Any help would be great,
Thanks,
M

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You're looking for `StringFormat`

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding myInt, StringFormat=\{0:N0\}}"/>
```

or

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding myInt, StringFormat={}{0:N0}}"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use a DataGridTextColumn you can use a StringFormatter on your binding

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MyNumber, StringFormat={0:#,0} {1:#,0}}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I accidentally gave you an undeserved +1 there... this solution does not build. The single apostrophes break the XAML!

Comment: @Heliac apostrophe marks are not required. `Binding="{Binding number, StringFormat={}{0:n2}}"` will show two decimal places e.g.

Comment: Apologies, I wrote that out on my phone and couldn't recall the syntax... I've updated the answer.