# thousand separator for integer in formatString

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to show the numbers in text block with thousand separator in xaml but without floating point.
how can i do it.
i tried the following codes:

```
StringFormat={}{0:N}
```

it shows floating point.

```
StringFormat={}{0:000'.'000}}
```

it shows 1234 like 001,234
how can it do it?

Comment: any sample input and desired output?

Comment: Have you tried `StringFormat={}{0:N0}`?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596654/wpf-datagrid-column-format-number-to-include-commas/18597072#18597072

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use

```
{Binding StringFormat={}{0:N0}}
```

The good [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mikehillberg/trying-out-binding-stringformat) about formatting in bindings.

Comment: Very Nice Article @Hamlet Hakobyan. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For me this worked:

```
Label Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='{}{0:N0}'}"
```