# Formatting the Cell Values of a DataGrid that is bound to a DataView/DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, string-formatting, itemssource

So I have a code that gets values from my MS Access database and shows it on my DataGrid, something like as follows:

C#

```
OleDbConnection dbConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=myDB.accdb");
dbConn.Open();

OleDbCommand dbCmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE stockID LIKE 'stockID'", dbConn);
OleDbDataAdapter dbAdap = new OleDbDataAdapter(dbCmd);
dbAdap.Fill(myDataSet, "myDataTable");

myDataGrid.ItemsSource = new DataView(myDataSet.Tables["myDataTable"]);
```

XAML

```
<DataGrid Name="myDataGrid"
          Margin="5"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          SelectionUnit="FullRow"
          HeadersVisibility="Column" />
```

So, `myDataGrid` would show all the columns and rows, some of which are of type `int` or `double` (see image).

I'd like to format each column to reduce the decimal places, and include thousands separators (1,234.56). Any help or reference would be great.

Thanks in advance.

myDataGrid

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596654/wpf-datagrid-column-format-number-to-include-commas this would give you hint.